# getElementById("myID").value returns "Cannot read property 'value' of null" error and when I console log "myID" I get the whole class text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my stateless function in which the user can put in a time value. 
As you can see I am setting the ID for the input field with props.UserInputTimeID (I think this may be part of the error). This is because I want to reuse this component with different ID's.

```
const UserInputTime = (props) => 
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    {props.UserInputTimeMessage}
                    <input type="time" id={props.UserInputTimeID} defaultValue={"00:01"} min="00:01" max={props.maxTime}></input>
                    <input onClick={props.userInputTimeHandler} type="submit" value="Send"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        )

    };
```

In my container (App.js) where I call to render this component I set the prop values as shown below. My ID's are set to "studyTimer" and "breakTimer"

```
render() {
    return (
        <div >

          <DisplayTimer UserInputTimeID={"studyTimer"}/>
          <UserInputTime
            UserInputTimeMessage={"Set the length of your study time from 1 - 59 minutes"}
            UserInputTimeID={"studyTimer"}
            maxTime={"00:59"}
            userInputTimeHandler={{/* todo - placeholder for function */}}
          /> {/*study timer*/}
            {console.log("A test to see what the value is  :  " + UserInputTime)}
          <DisplayTimer UserInputTimeID={"breakTimer"}/>
          <UserInputTime
            UserInputTimeMessage={"Set the length of your break from 1-20 minutes"}
            UserInputTimeID={"breakTimer"}
            maxTime={"00:20"}
            userInputTimeHandler={{/* todo - placeholder for function */}}
          /> {/*break timer*/}

          </div>
    );
  }
```

In my component DisplayTimer I have the following code which is where the error is showing. It says that the value for the ID is null.

```
const DisplayTimer = (props) =>
{

    let newTimerValue = document.getElementById(props.UserInputTimeID).value; 

    return(
        <div>

        </div>
    )
};
```

When I looked at the console the statement I got back was weird:

```
A test to see what the value is  :  function UserInputTime(props) //todo check if this variable should use camelcase or pascalcase
{
  return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 6
    },
    __self: this
  }, react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("form", {
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 7
    },
    __self: this
  }, props.UserInputTimeMessage, react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("input", {
    type: "time",
    id: props.UserInputTimeID,
    defaultValue: "00:01",
    min: "00:01",
    max: props.maxTime,
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 9
    },
    __self: this
  }), react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("input", {
    onClick: props.userInputTimeHandler,
    type: "submit",
    value: "Send",
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 10
    },
    __self: this
  })));
}
```

Comment: means: `document.getElementById(props.UserInputTimeID)` does not find the element......

Comment: sorry to be a pain but can you be more specific, what do you mean by element?

Comment: The element you are trying to reference..... It really makes no sense why you would even reference the element like this to read the value. You should just be referencing it through the react code.

Comment: okay thank you, i am just a beginner this is my first project, I will try to reference this value in another way